# WinHttpRequest Run time error (-2147012867)

Tags: excel, http, winhttprequest, vba

I am running the following code in 4 computers:
The code makes a simple HTTP request to a target server using POST.

```
Sub test()

    valueParam1 = "value1"
    valueParam2 = "value2"
    user = "myUser"
    pass = "myPass"
    headerName = "Content-Type"
    headerValue = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Url = "https://www.myURL.com" + "/Path1/Path2/File.php?"

    Set htttpObj = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    htttpObj.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 300000

    htttpObj.Open "POST", Url, False

    htttpObj.setRequestHeader headerName, headerValue

    htttpObj.Send ("param1=" & valueParam1 & "&param2=" & valueParam2 & "&username=" & user & "&psd=" & pass)

    response = htttpObj.responseText

End Sub
```

2 out of 4 computers run the code perfectly.
2 out of 4 computers show the following error message:

[image]

Run time error: -2147012867

The computers that run the code are using Windows10 version 10.0.14393
The computers that do not run the code use Windows7 version 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1
This error only happens after I edit the following file:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

I add the following information to the file to change the IP address of the hostname 'myURL.com':

149.56.23.106    myURL.com
149.56.23.106    www.myURL.com
[image]

Any ideas on how to investigate or solve this problem?

Comment: try increasing timeout times? Had similar issue recently, not with separate computer but with large dataset.

Comment: Does not work =(